# I am storing strings in a 2D array. However when I print the result the [0][0] space is blank. Can someone tell me how to occupy that space?

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array

How can I occupy the [0][0] space with information from the user. When it prints, it begins at [0][1] instead of [0][0]

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int sizeArray;

//Prompting user for number of users to be added
System.out.println("How many users are you going to add?");
sizeArray = scan.nextInt(); //Reading users to add

String user [][] = new String[sizeArray][2];


System.out.println("Enter name followed by unique password: ");

for(int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j< 2; j++) {
        user[i][j] =scan.nextLine();
    }
}
System.out.println("You entered: ");

for(int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        System.out.println(" Name["+i+"]["+j+"] = "+user[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.print("");
}
```

Comment: what is the question, do you wanna your method to print from index [0][1]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: `sizeArray = Integer.parseInt( scan.nextLine());`

Answer (score 1):

> When it prints, it begins at [0][1] instead of [0][0]

you're invoking the `scan.nextInt()` method before `scan.nextLine()`  which does not consume the last newline character of the user input hence the first `scan.nextLine()` within the loop consumes that newline character and when you attempt to retrieve the element at `[0][0]` within the `user` two-dimensional array, it will print an empty `string`.

a quick solution that will enable you to print the expect values starting at `[0][0]` is right after this:

```
System.out.println("Enter name followed by unique password: ");
```

insert this:

```
scan.nextLine();
```

now it becomes:

```
System.out.println("Enter name followed by unique password: ");
scan.nextLine(); // let this consume the newline character
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can´t believe it was that simple.

Comment: @cbc glad it helped ^^. don't forget to mark as accepted if the answer has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sizeArray;

        System.out.println("How many users are you going to add?");
        sizeArray = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

        String user[][] = new String[sizeArray][2];


        System.out.println("Enter name followed by unique password: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++) {
            String[] input = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                user[i][j] = input[j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You entered: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.println("Name[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + user[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("");
        }
    }
```

I suppose this is the answer for your problem? :)